# Как правильно отформатировать строку в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Мне нужно из строки допустим

```
str1 = "https://www.первый_сайт, https://www.второй_сайт"
```

нужно поместить в список (без запятой)

Есть ли какие нибудь методы для этого?

Comment: да, есть. split(), например. Только "форматировать строку" относится к выводу строки при печати.

Comment: только не забудь в методе сплит указать разделитель ', ' (запятая с пробелом)